# Using message queuing to decouple transactional updates to two systems?

Tags: database, transactions, message-queue, acid, eventual-consistency

In an [article on BASE as an ACID alternative](http://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=1394128), Dan Pritchett presents one option for decoupling a transaction spanning two tables, *Transaction* table (e.g. Buy/Sell transaction) and *User* table:

> [image]
>
> ***Source***: http://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=1394128

Dan also suggests that there is a problem with this approach:

> The message persistence is on the transaction host to avoid a 2PC
>   during queuing. If the message is dequeued inside a transaction
>   involving the user host, we still have a 2PC situation.
>
> ***Source***: http://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=1394128

I'm assuming that the messaging is persistent messaging, so that delivery is guaranteed.  In this case, I would expect the Dequeue operation to have no affect on the Queue operation thus completely decoupling the update of the *Transaction* and *User* tables and thus avoiding 2PC between those two tables?  There will be 2PC, but that will be:

- 2PC boundary 1:

  - Insert into *Transaction* table AND
  - insert into the message queue message persistence table
- 2PC boundary 2:

  - Update *User* table AND
  - remove message from message queue persistence table

Is anyone able to clarify where I am thinking about this wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There will be 2PC, but that will be:

**TL;DR**: You are correct about the two transactions but the first is *not* 2PC while the second is. That is what Fig 5 describes. The 2PC is why "we still have a 2PC situation".

---

The article has some difficulties. The `transaction` table has nothing to do with database transactions and should be called `purchases`. The "persistent queue" is just a table that represents a queue of changes. Also, it keeps proposing *non-solutions* that have "problems".

The proposal for using BASE involves replacing the user table by two tables `user_less_delta` and `delta` which together give the same information as `user`. (It then uses " `user` " for but `user_less_delta` but I'll use separate names.) However `delta` is kept on the host with `purchases`. Ie it does not require 2PC to implement transactions involving `purchases` with `delta` but does require 2PC to implement transactions involving `user_less_delta` with `delta`.

The Fig 5 BASE relaxation is to atomically transact (free of 2PC) `purchases` with `delta` then separately atomically 2PC transact various changes to `user_less_delta` with `delta`. This allows us to not have to 2PC every update to `user_less_delta` with `purchases` at the expense of `user_less_delta` not being as accurate as `user`. However this still assumes
2PCs for updating`user_less_delta` with `delta`.

I don't know what you mean by "boundary". (Other language like "persistent messaging" is also unclear.) But there are two kinds of transactions: non-2PC transactions on `purchases` with `delta` and 2PC transactions on `user_less_delta` with `delta`.

> Dan also suggests that there is a problem with this approach:
>
> > The message persistence is on the transaction host to avoid a 2PC during queuing. If the message is dequeued inside a transaction involving the user host, we still have a 2PC situation.

The "problem" with this solution is that there's still a 2PC involved. The "If" should just be "Since" because otherwise the code does not implement the distributed tables properly. Since the message is dequeued inside a transaction involving the user host, we still have a 2PC situation.

The article goes on to (allegedly) remove the 2PCs by having `delta` reflected in `user_less_delta` without 2PC at one rate but having `user_less_delta` reflected in `delta` without 2PC at another. Changes in `delta` that have already been processed are just ignored. (Wait! I haven't read that far! Ok now I have and that's what they propose.)

(Basically each distributed site *tries* to update and acknowledge the other and as acknowledgements are received advances its version of what has been acknowledged and what is yet to be acknowledged. A kind of Red Queen's race to finish a 2PC.)

Comment: Ah, thank you.  I didn't register the statement _'The message persistence is on the transaction host to avoid a 2PC during queuing'_ when I first read it.  Hopefully there won't be too many more questions on the rest of the article :)

Comment: PS We have (as I write) the same rep! 2,598

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty mad!